# geckofx-45, can user input on the webbrowser control be disabled?

Tags: geckofx

Geckofx-45, can user input on the webbrowser control be disabled?  Geckofx 33 had a geckowebbrowser.Enabled property you could set but its gone in 45.  Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps have a try here:
https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues?status=new&status=open&page=2